# Getting "Error code: 4 (Failure)" when uploading a file to CentOS using WinSCP

Tags: linux, centos, sftp, winscp

I am using WinSCP from last six months almost regularly.

Suddenly i am facing a issue that is, I am not able to upload a file in server using it.

Its throwing below error message:

```
General failure (server should provide error description).
Error code: 4
Error message from server: Failure

Common reasons for the Error code 4 are:
- Renaming a file to a name of already existing file. 
- Creating a directory that already exists.
- Moving a remote file to a different filesystem (HDD).
- Uploading a file to a full filesystem (HDD).
- Exceeding a user disk quota.
```

WinSCP log message:

```
. 2017-12-15 18:06:03.081 Cached directory change via ".." to "/home/centos".
. 2017-12-15 18:06:03.081 Getting current directory name.
. 2017-12-15 18:06:03.095 Directory content loaded from cache.
. 2017-12-15 18:06:03.714 Changing directory to "..".
. 2017-12-15 18:06:03.715 Getting real path for '/home/centos/..'
> 2017-12-15 18:06:03.715 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 24, Number: 41232
< 2017-12-15 18:06:03.723 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 40964
. 2017-12-15 18:06:03.723 Discarding reserved response
< 2017-12-15 18:06:04.504 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 31, Number: 41232
. 2017-12-15 18:06:04.504 Real path is '/home'
. 2017-12-15 18:06:04.504 Trying to open directory "/home".
> 2017-12-15 18:06:04.504 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 14, Number: 41479
< 2017-12-15 18:06:04.791 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 41479
. 2017-12-15 18:06:04.791 Getting current directory name.
. 2017-12-15 18:06:04.791 Listing directory "/home".
> 2017-12-15 18:06:04.792 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 14, Number: 41739
< 2017-12-15 18:06:05.074 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 41739
> 2017-12-15 18:06:05.075 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 41996
< 2017-12-15 18:06:05.358 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 423, Number: 41996
> 2017-12-15 18:06:05.359 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 13, Number: 42252
< 2017-12-15 18:06:05.643 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 42252
< 2017-12-15 18:06:05.643 Status code: 1
> 2017-12-15 18:06:05.644 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 42500
. 2017-12-15 18:06:05.644 ..;d;0;2015-07-07T11:20:17.000Z;3;"root" [0];"root" [0];r-xr-xr-x;0
. 2017-12-15 18:06:05.644 centos;d;0;2017-12-15T12:24:52.000Z;3;"centos" [1000];"centos" [1000];rwx------;0
. 2017-12-15 18:06:05.644 nagios;d;0;2016-08-23T12:06:16.000Z;3;"nagios" [1001];"nagios" [1001];rwx------;0
. 2017-12-15 18:06:08.658 Cached directory change via "centos" to "/home/centos".
. 2017-12-15 18:06:08.658 Getting current directory name.
. 2017-12-15 18:06:08.773 Directory content loaded from cache.
. 2017-12-15 18:06:49.957 Copying 1 files/directories to remote directory "/home/centos/" - total size: 871
. 2017-12-15 18:06:49.957   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: Yes; Mask: *.*
. 2017-12-15 18:06:49.957   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2017-12-15 18:06:49.957   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2017-12-15 18:06:49.959 File: 'C:\Documents\C_Programs\Bsearch_using_recursion.txt' [2016-05-03T09:58:13.902Z] [871]
. 2017-12-15 18:06:49.972 Copying "C:\Documents\C_Programs\Bsearch_using_recursion.txt" to remote directory started.
. 2017-12-15 18:06:49.973 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2017-12-15 18:06:49.973 Opening remote file.
> 2017-12-15 18:06:49.973 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 65, Number: 42755
< 2017-12-15 18:06:49.973 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 42500
. 2017-12-15 18:06:49.973 Discarding reserved response
< 2017-12-15 18:06:50.256 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 42755
< 2017-12-15 18:06:50.256 Status code: 4, Message: 42755, Server: Failure, Language:  
. 2017-12-15 18:06:50.256 Cannot create new file "/home/centos/Bsearch_using_recursion.txt", checking if it exists already
> 2017-12-15 18:06:50.256 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 49, Number: 43015
< 2017-12-15 18:06:50.543 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 29, Number: 43015
< 2017-12-15 18:06:50.543 Status code: 2, Message: 43015, Server: No such file, Language:  
* 2017-12-15 18:06:50.544 (ETerminal) General failure (server should provide error description).
* 2017-12-15 18:06:50.544 Error code: 4
* 2017-12-15 18:06:50.544 Error message from server: Failure
* 2017-12-15 18:06:50.544 
* 2017-12-15 18:06:50.544 Common reasons for the Error code 4 are:
* 2017-12-15 18:06:50.544 - Renaming a file to a name of already existing file.
* 2017-12-15 18:06:50.544 - Creating a directory that already exists.
* 2017-12-15 18:06:50.544 - Moving a remote file to a different filesystem (HDD).
* 2017-12-15 18:06:50.544 - Uploading a file to a full filesystem (HDD).
* 2017-12-15 18:06:50.544 - Exceeding a user disk quota.
. 2017-12-15 18:06:50.544 Asking user:
. 2017-12-15 18:06:50.545 Cannot create remote file '/home/centos/Bsearch_using_recursion.txt'. ("General failure (server should provide error description).
. 2017-12-15 18:06:50.545 Error code: 4
. 2017-12-15 18:06:50.545 Error message from server: Failure
. 2017-12-15 18:06:50.545 
. 2017-12-15 18:06:50.545 Common reasons for the Error code 4 are:
. 2017-12-15 18:06:50.545 - Renaming a file to a name of already existing file.
. 2017-12-15 18:06:50.545 - Creating a directory that already exists.
. 2017-12-15 18:06:50.545 - Moving a remote file to a different filesystem (HDD).
. 2017-12-15 18:06:50.545 - Uploading a file to a full filesystem (HDD).
. 2017-12-15 18:06:50.545 - Exceeding a user disk quota.")
> 2017-12-15 18:06:52.975 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 65, Number: 43267
< 2017-12-15 18:06:53.259 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 43267
< 2017-12-15 18:06:53.260 Status code: 4, Message: 43267, Server: Failure, Language:  
. 2017-12-15 18:06:53.260 Cannot create new file "/home/centos/Bsearch_using_recursion.txt", checking if it exists already
> 2017-12-15 18:06:53.260 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 49, Number: 43527
< 2017-12-15 18:06:53.543 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 29, Number: 43527
< 2017-12-15 18:06:53.543 Status code: 2, Message: 43527, Server: No such file, Language:  
* 2017-12-15 18:06:53.544 (ETerminal) General failure (server should provide error description).
* 2017-12-15 18:06:53.544 Error code: 4
* 2017-12-15 18:06:53.544 Error message from server: Failure
```

I google about the issue and found that it might be due to 100% full filesystem.

I checked the memory using below command in centos:

```
free -m
```

Output of the command:

```
              total        used        free       shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          32014       28612         310        1553        3091        1533
Swap:             0           0           0
```

It seems like that i have 1533 MP space available. But still i am not able to upload a small 1 Mb file.

df command output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       52416860 52416840        20 100% /
devtmpfs        16374100        0  16374100   0% /dev
tmpfs           16391320        0  16391320   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           16391320  1597928  14793392  10% /run
tmpfs           16391320        0  16391320   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            3278268        0   3278268   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs            3278268        0   3278268   0% /run/user/0
```

Can anyone provide any info in this regard.

Comment: On CentOS run `lsblk` and then when you find the partition, etc. in question where the files are uploaded on the FTP server, run `df /boot` for example where `/boot` will be the actual mountpoint in question. The filesystem and memory or swap is not the same thing. Also be sure something else is not moving files from the server like an internal process as I've seen that sort of thing cause this type of problem if I recall correctly. You can probably just run `df -all` to see everything on the filesystem.

Comment: I have already wrote you on Stack Overflow: *When re-posting there [on Super User], make sure you include a main error message (what you have posted are just additional details of the error), or even better a session log file.*

Comment: Use the "df" command to show the amount of free disk space. The free command doesn't help as it shows RAM.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have added the log,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that your file system is indeed full: `Use%` is `100%` for file system `/dev/vda1`, which should be used by the `/home/centos` path

Comment: Is there any way to can found the main storage file, it can't delete the everything in centos.

Comment: @Vishal This is Q&A site, not a forum. You asked one specific question, you got specific answer; if it answers your question then please accept it (click the tick on the left). If you have another question then ask a *separate* question. But do your research first; I'm pretty sure there are already questions about investigating disk usage.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for your information